# Remove end line in CSS Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with my CSS navigation bar. I am unable to remove the end line in the navigation bar. It looks out of place and unprofessional.

When i minus the width, it just moves the end tab below the navigation bar.

Any help or ideas on how to fix this?

[image]

**Code:**

```css
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu a {
  border: none;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu {
  height: 37px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: auto;
  border-color: #336699;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  list-style: inside none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  list-style: inside none;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  float: none;
  margin-left: -3px;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(55, 110, 166, 0.6);
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: verdana;
  border-right: 1px solid #336699;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 12px 20px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  top: -1px;
  bottom: -1px;
  right: -2px;
  z-index: 99;
  border-color: #3c3c3c;
}
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > a:after {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  right: 6px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 19px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a {
  /*padding-bottom: 14px;*/
  z-index: 999;
  border-color: #2B5681;
}
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > ul,
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > div {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:hover,
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a {
  background: #2B5681;
  border-color: #2B5681;
}
#cssmenu ul li > ul,
#cssmenu ul li > div {
  display: none;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px;
  background: #2B5681;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
#cssmenu ul li > ul {
  width: 200px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: -10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#cssmenu ul li > ul li {
  display: block;
  list-style: inside none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul li > ul li a {
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font: 10pt verdana;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(55, 110, 166, 0.6);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 20px;
}
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #2B5681;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2B5681 0%, #336699 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #2B5681), color-stop(100%, #336699));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2B5681 0%, #336699 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2B5681 0%, #336699 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2B5681 0%, #336699 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #2B5681 0%, #336699 100%);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  background: #336699;
  color: Orange;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
  color: orange;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:hover:before {
  border-top: 5px solid Orange;
}
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul style="display: table;">
    <li style="width: 108px;" class='active'><a runat="server" href='~/Applications/Sentinel/Default.aspx'><span>Home</span></a>
    </li>
    <li style="width: 118px;" class='has-sub'><a><span>Jobs</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li class='has-sub'><a runat="server" style="text-align: left;" href='~/Applications/Sentinel/Jobs.aspx'>Jobs List<span></span></a>
        </li>
        <li class='has-sub'><a runat="server" style="text-align: left;" href='~/Applications/Sentinel/AddJob.aspx'><span>Add New Job</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Add your html please

Comment: @RasmusGlenvig Done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this line to your css

```
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child > a, #cssmenu > ul > li:last-child > a:after {
  border-right: none;
}
```

This code just remove borders from your last menu item.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much

Comment: Might as well explain how this solved the problem for better clarity. thanks,.

Comment: @Aziz ok :) Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your css to remove last border:

```
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child a:after, #cssmenu > ul > li:last-child > a {
  border-right: 0px solid;
}
```